# Comparator/Sorting/Equatable methodology and return value

Tags: c#, sorting, compare, iequalitycomparer

Alright so I'm taking everything I've learned and trying to implement it in C#. Given that I have a background in Java my ride has been pretty smooth so far, but I'm running into issues into using the Comparer object and functions etc. I don't care about direct implementation/translation, but I want to know how C# compares two generic values. What does it use to sort them? Hashcode, or maybe some C#-specific methodology?

So just to clarify, I know how to sort, search, etc. using methods in C#. What I want to know is what's going on under the hood - what are the Comparer and other functions using to compare two values of generics?

Comment: `int CompareTo (object other)`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Are you using "generic" as generic term for "an object" or using "generic" as term for "C# generics"? :) Some sample code that shows what you are trying to understand could help. (While editing your post consider also removing "story of your life" text which does not directly relate to problem).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how C# compares two generic values

It doesn't/can't, that is why there are the ICompariable and IComparer interfaces..

> What I want to know is what's going on under the hood

If you're talking about types provided by .Net then..

> If you have an array of types (such as string or integer) that already support IComparer, you can sort that array without providing any explicit reference to IComparer. In that case, the elements of the array are cast to the default implementation of IComparer (Comparer.Default) for you.

[How to use the IComparable and IComparer interfaces in Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320727)  is probably the best article I've seen specific to your question.

> The role of **IComparable** is to provide a method of comparing two objects of a particular type
>
> The role of **IComparer** is to provide additional comparison mechanisms. For example, you may want to provide ordering of your class on several fields or properties, ascending and descending order on the same field, or both.

Comment: That's all well and good but I want to know what's going on under the hood. I know how to use the IComparer/IComparable/assorted methods and algorithms, and what I don't know how to use I can figure out easily enough. I suppose easiest way to phrase it is I want to see exactly what it does when it compares. Best way to do that is, clearly, to see the source code, but I'm buggered if I can find C# source code anywhere.

Comment: The link I provided clearly states exactly what's happening, at some point it's just `Note that the IComparer.Compare method requires a tertiary comparison. 1, 0, or -1 is returned depending on whether one value is greater than, equal to, or less than the other. The sort order (ascending or descending) can be changed by switching the logical operators in this method.`.